# Extending Gravity Forms Personality Quiz to determine multiple results

Tags: php, wordpress, gravityforms

I'm using the Personality Quiz add-on for Gravity Forms and would like to extend it's functionality. Currently it determines the "winner" of a multiple-choice quiz like this:

```
$scores = array_count_values( $quiz_questions );
$winners = array_keys( $scores, max( $scores ), true );
return $winners[0];
```

Rather than simply returning which option (A, B, or C) received the most clicks I'd like to use ranges of scores so that if "A" > 30 than $winners would be "Type 1", if "A">20 and "B">20 $winners would be "Type 2", if "B">20 and "C">20 $winners would be "Type 3", etc. I've been trying variations of this but not finding the error.

```
$scores = array_count_values( $quiz_questions );
        $k_count_total = count($scores($quiz_questions, "Kilo"));
        $v_count_total = count($scores($quiz_questions, "Victor"));
        $p_count_total = count($scores($quiz_questions, "Papa"));
        if ($v_count_total > 33) { $winners = "Victor"; } 
        elseif ($v_count_total > 17 && $p_count_total > 17) {$winners = "Victor-Papa";}
        elseif ($v_count_total > 17 && $k_count_total > 17) {$winners = "Victor-Kilo";} 
        elseif ($p_count_total > 33) {$winners = "Papa";}
        elseif ($p_count_total > 17 && $k_count_total > 17) {$winners = "Papa-Kilo";}
        elseif ($k_count_total > 33) {$winners = "Kilo";}
        elseif ($k_count_total > 15 && $v_count_total > 15 && $p_count_total > 15) {$winners = "VPK";}
 return $winners[0];
```

Comment: Why did you delete the question you already asked half a day ago? https://stackoverflow.com/q/65298775/1427878

Comment: _“but haven't had any luck so far”_ - and with _that_, you are not very likely to have more luck either. Please go read [ask].

Comment: Thanks @CBroe I've updated the question

Answer (score 1):

You may have figured this out already but on quick glance it looks like you have some syntax errors.

for example:
$scoress($$quiz_questions, "Kilo")
should be
$scores($quiz_questions, "Kilo")

Comment: Thanks for catching that @Rochelle Must've made those typos while copying over. I've updated the code now.